# LSTM prediction normalization

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, normalization, lstm

I am currently trying Ethereum price prediction with LSTM network in Keras and I have a little problem.

I am trying to predict 10 following prices from 40 previous prices. Time span between prices is 15 second, so I am predicting 2,5 minutes into the future.

My input data are: closing price, open price, lowest price and highest price. I normalize the data between 0 and 1, since my activation function in fully connected layer is linear. I normalize each sequence independently based on minimum and maximum value of the whole sequence.

This model works fine when I test it with past data, since I have both input prices and the prices I am trying to predict, so when I denormalize the data based on minimum and maximum of the whole sequence, the prediction is pretty accurate.

However when I try to predict live data, I do not have the last 10 prices from the sequence, so I have to denormalize my output based on only 40 input values, which is where the problem is. The live result will never be as good as the testing result.

I tried to normalize my data based on 40 input prices from the sequence at the training, but it kind of threw off my whole prediction.

I also tried to normalize between -1 and 1 based on 40 input values and change my output activation function to tanh, but it still did not work correctly. My prediction mostly showed straight line with no increase or decrease in value.

My training data consist of around 61 000 rows of prices and I took 85% as training set, 20% of training set as validation set and 15% as testing set.

Do you have any idea where the problem could be? I can also provide some data about my architecture and training if needed.

Comment: you are wasting your time if you think you can make money off trading signals generated in this manner.

Comment: Are you asking a Python coding question or how to fix your learning/prediction process?

Comment: @wwii A little bit from both.

Comment: @braaterAfrikaaner I am not trying to make money from it. I want to try it, if is possible.